# What does the expression $\text{plim}_{n\to\infty}\hat\theta_n=\theta$ mean?

Tags: probability, central-limit-theorem

What does the expression $\text{plim}_{n\to\infty}\hat\theta_n=\theta$ mean?

where $\hat\theta$ is an unbiased estimator of $\theta$

Comment: appreciate if can teach me how to type this out in Word too.. thank you!

Comment: I think it might be intended to convey convergence in probability.

Comment: The probability that they're at least a little apart vanishes as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Please edit your title to be intelligible. You can use math typesetting with Matjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: seems like convergence in probability.

Answer (score 1):

$\DeclareMathOperator*{\plim}{plim}$
$$\plim_{n\to\infty} \theta_n = \theta \;\; \text{if and only if} \;\;
\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathrm{Pr}(|\theta_n-\theta|\geq\epsilon)=0 \, ,\;\; \text{for every} \;\; \epsilon>0\,$$

Or, in approximating English, the limit, as $n \to \infty$, of the probability that $\theta_n$ is $\geq$ any given "distance" from $\theta$ equals $0$.

This is referred to as "convergence in probability", as @SiXUlm observes in comments above.

Comment: hi sir, i have edited my question for better clarity. appreciate your help..

Comment: Whether or not $\hat{\theta}$ is an unbiased estimator of $\theta$ is irrelevant to the definition of $\text{plim}$.  If you look carefully at the definition, and think about the meaning, you'll see that whether $\hat{\theta}$ is unbiased or not plays no part in it.

Comment: @jbowman That's consistency, right, not unbiasedness?

Comment: @Dave - Correct; the (sequence of ) estimator(s) $\hat{\theta_n}$ in the question is consistent, well, more precisely, is consistent if the above holds for all $\theta \in \Theta$ where $\Theta$ is the parameter space.

Comment: @jbowman As in $bar{X}$ converges to $\mu$ whether $\mu = 5$ or $\mu = 500$? (And do I want $\bar{x}$ the value or $\bar{X}$ the random variable? I think it should be $\bar{x}$.)

Comment: @Dave - right, and you want $\bar{x}$, since that's the estimator.